# How to replace a value in a pandas df with an interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, outliers

I have a dataframe `df` that looks something like that

```
print(df)
x     outlier_flag
10    1
NaN   1
30    1
543  -1
50    1
```

I would like to substitute values flagged with `outlier_flag==-1` with the interpolated values between `row['A][i-1]` and `row['A][i+1]`, means I want to substitute the presented wrong value of 543 with 40.

What I could do is

```
df['x'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.nan if row['outlier_flag']==-1 else row['x'], axis=1)
df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=3, inplace=True)
```

But I don't want to do this, because this would also interpolate `nan` values in `df['x']` that are not marked with `outlier_flag==-1` (see for that the second row)! Pure `nan` values, not marked by the flag, I want to keep as `nan` for a task later on.

**So, is there a way to do the interpolation in place, even for a value like `543` that is not `nan`?**

I tried doing

```
df['x'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['x'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=3) if row['outlier_flag']==-1 else row['x'], axis=1)
```

But this throws an error, because only `nan` can be interpolated and `543` is `int`. Do you have a suggestion for me? Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way that you can use [`interpolate()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-interpolate) as you intend to.

You can first create a list containing the index of the rows which have -1 in outlier flag, and replace the values in x to be `np.nan` using `loc`:

```
incl = df.index[df['outlier_flag'] == -1].tolist()
df.loc[df.index.isin(incl), 'x'] = np.nan

>>> df
      x  outlier_flag
0  10.0             1
1   NaN             1
2  30.0             1
3   NaN            -1
4  50.0             1
```

Then, you can use `np.where` to check whether x `isnull()` and whether that particular index is in the list you created, and apply your interpolation:

```
df['x']= np.where( (df['x'].isnull()) & (df.index.isin(incl)), df['x'].interpolate(),df['x'])
```

Which prints:

```
      x  outlier_flag
0  10.0             1
1   NaN             1
2  30.0             1
3  40.0            -1
4  50.0             1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `np.where`:

```
df['x'] =  np.where(df['outlier_flag'] == -1, (df['x'].shift(1) + df['x'].shift(-1))/2, df['x'])
print(df)

      x  outlier_flag
0  10.0             1
1   NaN             1
2  30.0             1
3  40.0            -1
4  50.0             1
```

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer! It would be a kind of a solution. But is there a way to use `.interpolate()`? Because, I want to use a polynomial interpolation, not a linear. And sometimes the values of `df['x'].shift(1) ` are `nan` and your interpolation method would result in a `nan`, too, bit `,interpolate()` would be able to handle such a case. Any ideas?

Comment: @NeStack One option you could do is to create another dataframe that contains those NAN and delete NAN from the current dataframe and then assign for X to NAN with its -1 for outlier flag. After that do the interpolation and the finally combine dataframe